# How do I draw a context menu next to my object?

Tags: unity

I want to show a menu next to an item in an inventory. This is what I try to rebuild:
[image]

I do this by placing a canvas in 3D world space next to the inventory:
[image]

As I don't want the menu to be rotated, I rotated the menu the opposite X value as the camera. The camera has an X rotation of -11, so I rotate the menu by 11 to make it look straight:

[image]

Since I don't want the menu to get stuck in the case, I move it closer to the camera:

[image]

One can see that the menu is now offset to the left and to the top because of the camera perspective.

How could I offset the menu in such a way that it still aligns with the right top corner of the item?

Thank you!

Comment: You were on a much better track with your previous question, when you said you thought a screen space overlay canvas could be a good way to go. What made you go back to using a world space canvas? Note that again here, you're asking about your guessed-at solution ("apply rotation and shift offsets to the world space canvas so it looks like a screen space canvas") instead of asking about the problem you want to solve ("how do I draw a context menu next to my object") - this is another case of the [X/Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/), which can lead to you getting worse answers.

Comment: @DMGregory Since nobody replied, I thought that my approach of a Screen Space Canvas is so absurd that nobody has experience with it  and is therefore the wrong approach.

Comment: I replied, telling you that you don't need to ask StackExchange for permission to try using screen space overlay, or any other mode/setting. The settings are there for you to play with to your heart's content, no matter whether some internet stranger thinks you "should" do it that way or not. If you'd just tried what your hunch was saying could work, you might have found the solution on your own. So, your first step should always be: try it. Then, if things go wrong, and you can't find a way to solve it, ask for help. You don't need preemptive help if nothing's gone wrong yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put a UI element in perspective only to fight and counter that perspective. You're just making your life more complicated that way.

Instead you can use a canvas in "Screen Space - Overlay" mode like you'd asked about previously.

Then place the position of your menu to match the on-screen position of the object you want it to follow, something like this:

```
void PlaceMenuAtWorldPosition(Vector3 wordPosition, RectTransform menu, Camera camera) {
    Vector2 screenPoint = camera.WorldToScreenPoint(worldPosition);

    Vector2 uiPoint;
    RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(
        (RectTransform)menu.parent, // Local space to place the point into.
        screenPoint,
        null,         // We're in screen space overlay, no need for camera perspective.
        out uiPoint   // The resulting point in the container's space. 
    );

    menu.anchoredPosition = uiPoint;
}
```

Comment: A question, please: What do you mean by "point in the container's space"? What is the container? Also, a spello: "wordPosition" should be "worldPosition". You typed that flying blind. Wow. :-)

Comment: The container is the parent object, likely your canvas, but it could be a different object if you have additional levels of hierarchy in your setup.

Comment: My setup seems to be different than what you had in mind. Do you think you could describe what ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle does in this case? I have read the doc, but I don't understand why you use it.

Comment: It takes a point on the screen, and transforms it to a point in a RectTransform's local space. We use it to translate between the pixel coordinates of the screen and the UI coordinate system of your canvas or layout container.

Comment: Thank you, fully understood now!